# Как получить номер телефона пользователя написавшего в Telegrambot?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Можно ли как-то программным способом получить номер телефона пользователя, написавшего в `Telegrambot` (`webhook`)?

Когда при тестировании пытался это сделать из объекта класса `Update`, то мне возвращался `null`:

```
string phoneNumber = update.Message.Contact.PhoneNumber;
```

При этом бот периодически запрашивает мои данные, в том числе и телефон при начале диалога и спрашивает "хочу ли я поделиться" этими данными.

Comment: Нужно сделать Reply кнопку с запросом контакта, тогда при ее клике будет запрошено у клиента подтверждение, что он хочет поделиться номером телефона и боту придет номер телефона. Ботов писал на питоне, поэтому с c# сходу не подскажу подробности, поэтому лучше укажите в вопросе используемую библиотеку для работы с телеграммом

Answer (score 2):

```
kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
kb.add(KeyboardButton('Отправить контакт', request_contact=True)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
def contact(message):
    if message.contact is not None:
        print(message.contact.phone_number)
```

- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#contact
- https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#types

Comment: У автора, судя по синтаксису, c#, а не питон :)